# scikit learn train_test_split for loop

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to create 5 different training and test sets by looping train_test_split like:

```
for i in range(0,5):
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=i)
```

and I want to create a list that stores 5 different splits and from each split I can run testing. My question is how should I create a list to store X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test and afterwards how do you call each split from the list to run test?
For the test I mean running ml algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion as a simple solution:

```
datas = []
for i in range(0,5):
    a,b,c,d = train_test_split(features, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=i)
    datas.append((a,b,c,d)
```

if you want get any sets from datas you can use this code. For expample you want use to index 3.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = datas[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

To OPs question for creating 5 different test and train dataframes, the following should work:

```
from random import randint
trainX_list=[[]]
trainY_list=[[]]
testX_list=[[]]
testY_list=[[]]
for i in range (0,4):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=randint(100, 1000))
    trainX_list.append([X_train])
    trainY_list.append([y_train])
    testX_list.append([X_test])
    testY_list.append([y_test])
```

You can then do `pd.concat(trainX_list[i])` to view each dataframe!